# Jenkins stops responding after trying to run a job

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, jenkins

I'm currently trying to repair a Jenkins installation, something I've never done before, and am having trouble. I've gotten to the point where I can view all of the jobs and run a build. However, most of the time I start one, the Jenkins UI immediately stops responding to any http requests, including the build request. The browser just spins indefinitely. The only way to fix this is to perform a systemctl restart on jenkins. Note that the build id is incremented, but never actually happens. A few times the build has actually gone on to occur and the build id is up based on how many times I've gotten the UI to hang and needed to restart it.

This is on RHEL 7.9. Jenkins version is 2.49. I've checked jenkins.log when this happens but it doesn't have anything useful. Note that the jenkins process is still running after things break; it's just the web application that seems to stop doing anything but accept (and not answer) requests.

I'm very new to this, so please let me know what useful information I can provide that I've probably missed.

Comment: Repair from what?

Comment: From the UI not working almost at all; when I started it was either blank or would show the 'please wait while Jenkins is getting ready' message indefinitely.

Comment: You could jstack it when it hangs.  Also check for any stderr output but presumably that would already be in the log dir...

Comment: Oh wow! I haven't used jstack before. I just tried it on my hung jenkins process and it reported a deadlock! I hope this is the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After the awesome tip about jstack from rogerdpack, I was able to run jstack -F  for my hung process and saw immediately that there was a deadlock on a monitor object that was associated with both whatever executes the job I wanted to start and the Console Handler for logging.

After looking at the list of blocked threads, it became clear that this was due to logging; we added custom logging to the Jenkins Java command when it broke down (since we couldn't access the UI to view logs). After fixing things enough for the UI to load, I still left that logging in. Multiple threads were blocking on logging classes. After I removed the custom logging and restarted Jenkins, things seem to be running smoothly.

Thanks again to rogerdpack for the info!

Comment: You should update the xdetails in your Q and mark as self-answered